# Safe to replace my domain name on my Django application?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, certbot

Will I face any repercussions for replacing the domain name on my Django application? It's running on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx/Gunicorn. Apart from `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in my `settings.py`, the other locations I would replace the domain is my Nginx conf file and also my Digital Ocean nameservers.

A possible concern I have is that I've secured my previous domain with certbot, so I'm not sure what will happen when I remove that domain and put in the new one, as there are certbot files configured only for that domain.